# What is wrong with the convert function?

Tags: python, type-conversion, decimal, cs50

```
def main():
    askForTime = input("What time is it? ").strip().split()
    time = convert(askForTime)
    if 7 <= time <= 8:
        print("breacfast time")
    elif 12 <= time <= 13:
        print("lunch time")
    elif 18 <= time <= 19:
        print("dinner time")



def convert(clock):
    if "p.m" in clock or "pm" in clock:
        hours, minutes = clock[0].split(":")
        timer = (float(hours) + 12) + (float(minutes) / 60)
        return timer
    else:
        hours, minutes = clock[0].split(":")
        timer = float(hours) + (float(minutes) / 60)
        return timer


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
convert successfully returns decimal hours
    expected "7.5", not "Error\n"
```

I checked my program, and the convert function does indeed produce decimal hours.
Could someone please explain to me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect the `askForTime` value you get from this line:

```
def main():
    askForTime = input("What time is it? ").strip().split()
```

When you do, you will discover that it is returning the input as a list. (That's because you used `.split()` - the return is a list.)  Your `convert()` function "works" because it expects a list. However, `check50` tests by calling with a string, like this:

```
pset_1/meal/SO_74635140/ $ python
>>> from meal import convert
>>> print(convert("7:30"))
```

When you run as shown above, you will get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/workspaces/68927141/pset_1/meal/SO_74635140/meal.py", line 19, in convert
    hours, minutes = clock[0].split(":")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Also, you have "breakfast time" misspelled as "breacfast time". That will cause another `check50` error once you fix the 1st problem.

Comment: Thank you so much; I was beginning to lose my mind.